# Stuck adding list selection listener to program

Tags: java, swing

I asked a similar question yesterday and while I got some direction I am now stuck. I have a program that contains a GUI with two lists which are side-by-side. The first list (which I will refer to as left) contains a number of items which are parsed from an uploaded file.

The other list (I'll call the right list) is empty by default. The user can use some buttons to transfer items between the two lists. At runtime the items in the right list will be kept and the left list will be discarded. Now I have successfully added a counter that shows dynamically the total count of items for each list.

I had an idea yesterday that I want to add another dynamic counter that will show the user how many items are selected in the left list (but haven't been moved yet). The reason for this is that users may have very large lists (300+ items) and need to move a certain amount (like 50).. Having a counter to show how many items they have currently selected will save them a little time.

I understand to do this I need to use a list selection listener that will have a method to set the text of my JLabel. The problem is I can't figure out the method to get the size of the list.

Here is where my list is created.

```
input = new DefaultListModel();
```

Here it is populated with an array of items that was filled during a buffered writer based on the upload file.

```
String[] inputItems = new String[MainWriter.entryDetails.size()];
inputItems = MainWriter.entryDetails.toArray(inputItems);

for(int i = 0; i < inputItems.length; i++){
            input.addElement(inputItems[i]);
        }
```

Creating the list:

```
inputDetails = new JList(output);
        inputDetails.setVisibleRowCount(10);
        inputDetails.setFixedCellHeight(20);
        inputDetails.setFixedCellWidth(400);
        inputDetails.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

        //Creates a new scroll pane for the inputDetails. 
        JScrollPane list2 = new JScrollPane(inputDetails);
```

Here is my attempt at creating the list selection listener..

```
inputDetails.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {

                selectedCount.setText(inputDetails.);

            }



        });
```

As you see I'm not sure what the best method would be to set the text to the currently selected items.

I believe that is enough information to illustrate my problem. I want to have the line Selected Items and then dynamically say how many items in the left list the user has highlighted.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

As suggested I added the following:

```
inputDetails.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {


                String counter = Integer.toString(inputDetails.getSelectedIndices().length);
                selectedCount.setText("Currently Selected Transactions: "+counter);

            }



        });
```

however the JLabel does not appear to be updating, can someone advise me on the problem?

Comment: `I want to have the line Selected Items and then dynamically say how many items in the left list the user has highlighted` - You were given that answer if your other question. Did you even read the JList API for the method that was given?

Comment: I did read the JList API but I couldn't find the method that would solve my problem.. The method that was suggested in the answer did not work.

Comment: Why do you think the method will be in the API if it doesn't work. Well actually the API tells you the method is deprecated and then tells you which method to use. So why do you think the method would be in the API if the method doesn't work. If you think a method doesn't work then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) when you ask your question because it is more likely a problem with your code, not the APII!!

Comment: I realize the problem is with my code. The problem is that the program is very long and I'm not sure how to isolate the code in a way that will conform to SSCCE due to it's length. I was really just asking how to get the total selected indices.

Comment: `I was really just asking how to get the total selected indices. – jesric1029 2 mins ago` - and you where given the answer. Try it again now. You simply replace the statement you use in your accepted answer with the statement you where given yesterday. Prove to yourself that both methods work. You never know in the future when you will need to use either method, so learn how to use both now.

Comment: `The problem is that the program is very long and I'm not sure how to isolate the code in a way that will conform to SSCCE` - your current program has absolutely nothing to do with the SSCCE. Your question is how to get the number of selected items. So you create a frame with a JList and you add a ListSelectionListener to the JList. In the listener you display the number of selected items. The whole program will be about 20 lines of code. Most times when you create the SSCCE you will solve the problem because you are forced to simplify the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I am still pretty new to Java. I was thrust into a position where I have to create programs at my place of employment. Maybe I get stressed and ask for help too soon. I will try to spend more time simplifying the problem before posting questions in the future.

Comment: `I will try to spend more time simplifying the problem before posting questions in the future.` - good luck :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the listener, selectedCount.getSelectedIndices().length will tell you how many items are currently selected.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much that was the method I was looking for that I could not find anywhere.. Very good that does what I need.

Comment: @jesric1029, `that was the method I was looking for that I could not find anywhere` - not true, you were given an answer yesterday. This method returns the indexes. The other method returns the items. In both cases you can get the count of the indexes or the items since one method returns an Array and the other returns a List.

Comment: Thanks for your help camickr.

Comment: ListSelectionModel can returns ....